# Parallax Scrolling in both directions

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, parallax, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to create parallax scrolling site with help of [Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/) But I want to use non typical animation. This animation should go from top to bottom, then stops at the middle of the page and going back( from the middle to top ).
Scrollorama author said that this type of animation doesn't support by scrollorama, neither his new plugin SuperScrollorama.
Maybe someone could suggest me another plugin that have this feature.

Comment: Have you tried to implement it in regular jQuery? jQuery's animation functions are pretty easy. You are trying to do custom animation; why try and squeeze your requirements into a 3rd party plugin if the code is relatively simple (at first glance your animation sounds pretty simple)?

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot   I need some other features from this plugin( like grow, scale and fly ). I have about 8 sections with different animations.

Comment: So, as you scroll down the page, you want an object to fly in from the top, settle at the middle of the page, then start going back up to where it came from as the user continues to scroll. Is that correct?

Comment: Consider [**Scrolling Parallax**](http://jonraasch.com/blog/scrolling-parallax-jquery-plugin#more-59) which is a different parallax jQuery plugin that supports reverse animation. Perhaps you can use event listener for scroll position and then change the animation direction when the center of the webpage is reached. That said, it's then evident once you scroll back up the event listener is ignored. Therefore, no parallax plugin will do this since your issue is with browser scroll, not parallax scroll. The workaround is to use clone elements below the center element and animate those in reverse.

Comment: @arttronics - I don't understand what you meant: "no parallax plugin will do this since your issue is with browser scroll". I had no problem hooking callbacks into a scroll event, up or down.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot, OP Reference: *"I need some other features from this plugin..."*. My awareness of current ready-to-use Parallax Plugins operate their parallax animations in a one-way direction that's hooked to the mousewheel/browser scroll event since there is only 1 single scrollbar, that of the browser. Your method contains a separate inner scrollbar to overcome this limitation but lacks the OP's other requirements (like grow,scale, and fly). Instead of inner scrollbar to overcome limitation, see cloned objects idea in  previous message, e.g.: Not "A, B, C, reverse" but "A,B,C,B,A"

Answer (score 6):

I've never seen Scrollorama before and it intrigued me, so [I built something to do what you're asking](http://jsfiddle.net/RustyTheBoyRobot/deZVc/3/). It isn't a plugin; I wanted the scrolling code to be simple and not cluttered with plugin-type code. I think that turning it into a plugin would be quite simple, so I'll leave that to you (unless you need some help there).

**Explanation of Code**

jQuery has a [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function to determine how far from the top the container is scrolled. Using the height of the element that is inside the scroll area and the height of its container, we can determine what percent the container has been scrolled:

```
scrollAmount / (totalSize - visibleSize)
```

*(We have to subtract off the container's height `visibleSize` in order to get correct results. Since `scrollTop()` returns the number of pixels from the top of the element that are hidden, scrolling all the way to the bottom will give us `totalSize - visibleSize`, not just `totalSize`)*

We can use that percent to determine when to move up, down or stay in the same position. The `repositionBanner()` function takes the scroll percent and decides what to do with the animated element. In my code, I chose to have the element move into position from 0-30%, hold its position from 30-70% and fly back to its original position from 70-100%.

*(All of my code assumes that you are dealing with vertical scrolling. The same concepts can be applied to horizontal scrolling by using `left` and `width` instead of `top` and `height`)*

Answer (score 1):

This isn't even close to being as elegant as RustyTheBoyRobot's answer but you can achieve this by wrapping the element in another container element that's transparent. You can then animate the container in, and the original element out.

Example:

```
//animate in
scrollorama.animate('#elementToAnimateContainer',{
   delay: 0,
   duration: 100,
   property:'left',
   start:-3000,
   end: 0,
   pin: true
});

//animate out
scrollorama.animate('#elementToAnimate',{
   delay: 500,
   duration: 100,
   property:'left',
   start:0,
   end: 3000,
   pin: true
});
```

The only issue is that the container will still be on the screen, but if set to transparent you wont see it. You could always `$('#elementToAnimateContainer').remove()` it later, or set `pointer-events:none;` etc.

As I say, it isn't pretty, but it'll do what you asked.

Comment: Maybe you could just reverse it; have the child move out of the parent *first*, then have the parent move away for the second part of the animation. This would keep unused containers off the screen.